# How to add a specific page to the table of contents in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am working on my master's thesis. I have to put a specific page for the thesis to be approved by the discussion committee at the beginning.

This page is found in the University's Thesis Writing Guide and has a specific format that I cannot change, in terms of font types, font sizes, margins, etc. So I created it in Word and then inserted it into a latex document as a PDF.

Now I want to add this page to the table of contents.

I tried using the command

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Examination Committee Approval}
```

but I encountered two problems: First, a blank page was added before the approval page. Second, when clicking on the page in the table of contents, it goes to the beginning of the thesis, not to the Approval page itself.

I also tried this command

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{\color{blue}Examination Committee Approval}}
```

The page was added in the ToC as a text without a link to the page and without numbering as well.

Is there any way I can add this page to the ToC without problems?
The document type that I use is "extreport" with `TexStudio Editor`

**Edit:**

This is part of my work, maybe it helps finding the issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=cyan,citecolor=black,linktocpage=false,hyperindex=true}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman} 
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Examination Committee Approval}
    \begin{center}
        
        \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{‏‏approval page en}}
        
    \end{center}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, with only the strictly meded to compile "as is",  i.e., a document, starting with `\documentclass{book}` and ending with `\end{document}`,  and obviously that also show that  problem (and  only that problem), but  without irrelevant packages, unknow images, text, includes, etc.  for the question. If you are using a custom  class, try to use  the standard `book` instead. Otherwise, clarify  where it comes from.

Comment: I add it, @Fran; 
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I guess you should remove the first `\newpage`. Also: possibly there is a contradiction in `\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]`. If you need to include a full already made page from elsewhere, perhaps you'd better use `\includepdf` of `pdfpages` package.

Comment: With hyperref you also need `\phantomsection` to create the links.

Comment: BTW, `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...}` formats the text using `\l@chapter`.  `\addtocontents` performs no formatting at all, but it will expand any macros before writing them to the aux file.  You need to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Iacobus1983; you solved the first problem. I am really thankful and grateful for your help.

Comment: Thank you, @JohnKormylo; the command ```\phantomsection``` works without any problem. My appreciation and gratitude for helping me.

Comment: Thank you all, your contributions solved my problem.
How can I vote for your comments and choose them as the answer to my question? "^^

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by adding `\phantomsection` right before the `\addcontentsline` command, and placing both inside `\makebox`.

```
\newpage
    \begin{center}
        
        \makebox[\textwidth]{
            \phantomsection
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Examination Committee Approval}
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{deutsch.jpg}
            }
        
    \end{center}
```